# Is libevent required for building memcached for windows?

Tags: memcached, libevent

I accidentally deleted my previous post.  Could I know exactly why I should compile libevent to be able to build memcached?  Actually, I can already use memcached for windows without compiling libevent and I also installed memcached as a service.  Nothing odd happens.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.  The rest of it doesn't make sense.  You're saying you use it without libevent, but are asking why you can't.  I can assure you that whatever it is you think you're running isn't memcached if it's not using libevent.  Understand the role of libraries (and libevent in particular) to know why this is true.

Comment: Well, thanks.  But how can I compile it then when I'm using Visual Studio 2008?

Comment: I tried the steps at http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/ but it didn't work.

Comment: And I'm using memcached 1.2.6 from Danga Interactive along with MemCacheD Manager. Does it use libevent? I guess it is. I just want to make sure.

Comment: One more thing, I'm using the binary file so I'm asking how to compile libevent since I want to try to compile the latest source version of memcached by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old but just for the record: you installed the exe that already have the lib included. You would need libevent library if you're trying to build the exe from the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Libevent is one of the easiest things I've had to compile on Windows-- at least using Mingw. If you want really easy, just use the memcached binary available at Northscale labs website: http://labs.northscale.com/memcached-packages/